# Nested FB.api calls not firing, javascript SDK

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, nested, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the facebook javascript API and trying to nest FB.api calls as demonstrated below. The first FB.api call is working fine but the nested one isn't firing. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
FB.api('/' + fbId1, function (response1) {
    //Do Something with response1
    FB.api('/' + fbId2, function (response2) {
        //Do Something with response2      
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem might exist in the `//Do Something with response1` part of your code.  What you've shown here looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

The variable I had fbId2 stored in was outside the closure of the first FB.api. Using the jQuery $.proxy function I solved the problem with the change below.

```
FB.api('/' + fbId1, $.proxy(function (response1) {
    //Do Something with response1
    FB.api('/' + fbId2, function (response2) {
        //Do Something with response2      
    });
},this));
```